# Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function on object creation

Tags: javascript

```
function coordinate(x, y) {
    this.x = x,
    this.y = y
}

function generateBaracade(numBlocks) {
    var coordinate = getRandomBaracadeCoordinate();
    var xStyle = expandDirection.down;
    var yStyle = expandDirection.right;
    var xNumBlocks = findRandomFactor(numBlocks);
    var yNumBlocks = numBlocks / xNumBlocks;

    //figure out which way to expand the blocks
    if (coordinate.x + xNumBlocks > xBlocks) {
        xStyle = expandDirection.left;
    } else {
        xStyle = expandDirection.right;
    }

    if (coordinate.y + yNumBlocks > yBlocks) {
        yStyle = expandDirection.down;
    } else {
        yStyle = expandDirection.up;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i <= xNumBlocks - 1; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j <= yNumBlocks - 1; j++) {
            var tempBlock = Object.create(block);
            tempBlock.type = "obstruction";
            tempBlock.color = "grey";
            tempBlock.illegalTerrain = true;
            tempBlock.coordinate = new coordinate(coordinate.x + (i * xStyle), coordinate.y + (j * yStyle));
            blockContainer[coordinate.x + (i * xStyle)][coordinate.y + (j * yStyle)] = tempBlock;
        };
    };
}
```

I get the 'Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function' on the line:

```
tempBlock.coordinate = new coordinate(coordinate.x + (i * xStyle), coordinate.y + (j * yStyle));
```

This is strange as I am following the mozilla guide to doing this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

EDIT: Source for getRandomBaracadeCoordinate. The return statement is exactly what I want to do, and executes without error.

```
function getRandomBaracadeCoordinate() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * (xBlocks)));
    var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * (yBlocks)));
    return new coordinate(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are shadowing the `coordinate` function by giving something else the same name on the first line of `getBaracade`:

```
var coordinate = getRandomBaracadeCoordinate();
```

Whatever `getRandomBaracadeCoordinate()` returns isn't a function, so `new coordinate` throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

`coordinate` is an object containing `{ x, y }` and initialized here:

```
var coordinate = getRandomBaracadeCoordinate();
```

```
tempBlock.coordinate = new coordinate(coordinate.x + (i * xStyle), coordinate.y + (j * yStyle));
```

Probably you mistyped `new coordinate()` instead of `new Coordinate()` (if `Coordinate` is a class).

You should look at the source of `getRandomBaracadeCoordinate()` — if it returns an object of some class, you should create an instance of this class. Otherwise, if it returns a simple `{ x:50, y:15 }` object, you can create it inline:

```
tempBlock.coordinate = { x: coordinate.x + (i * xStyle), y: coordinate.y + (j * yStyle) };
```

Comment: Your answer doesnt seem right. Source:

function getRandomBaracadeCoordinate() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * (xBlocks)));
    var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * (yBlocks)));
    return new coordinate(x, y);
}

I dont see why I can't do the same in the other function.

Comment: Ahh, now I see it. You've overridden a class named `coordinate` with a variable named `coordinate`. Change it's name to something else: `var coord = getRandomBaracadeCoordinate()`

Comment: `getRandomBaracadeCoordinate` is a function, but `getRandomBaracadeCoordinate()` returns an object, and on the first line of `generateBaracade` you're assigning that object to the variable `coordinate`, which overwrites ("shadows") the `coordinate` function inside `generateBaracade`. Later in `generateBaracade` when you do `new coordinate`, `coordinate` is still that object, not a function, so it throws an error.

Comment: This error is exactly the reason why there's an often-used convention to start class names with upper case and variable names with lower case.